# How to access listview in viewpager from activity for update - on created pages

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Hello Android developers,

I need to update ListView showned in tabs created in Fragments via PagerAdapter from Activity which starts theese fragments and PagerAdapter. But I dont know, how to get particular listview in active tab.

I know about notifyDataSetChanged over listview adapter but I dont know, how to access it from activity.

Here are more details.

I have following class:

```
public class ChannelsListTabsFragment extends Fragment {

    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private ChannelCountriesModel[] tabTitles;

    private Context applicationContext;

    private String session;

    private long time_offset;

    // Nastaveni listview, když se klikne
    private ListView listViewFragment;

    public static ChannelsListTabsFragment newInstance(String session, ChannelCountriesModel[] tabTitles, long time_offset)
    {
        ChannelsListTabsFragment fragment = new ChannelsListTabsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArray("tabTitles", tabTitles);
        args.putString("session", session);
        args.putLong("time_offset", time_offset);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ChannelsListTabsFragment()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbet, container, false);
        System.out.println("onCreateView");
        applicationContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        tabTitles = (ChannelCountriesModel[]) getArguments().getParcelableArray("tabTitles");
        session = getArguments().getString("session");
        time_offset = getArguments().getLong("time_offset");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.channels_list_tabs_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ListChannelsPagerAdapter(session, tabTitles));

        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);

        mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.myred);
            }

            @Override
            public int getDividerColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.myred);
            }
        });

        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        if (v.getId()==R.id.channelList) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            Object o = listViewFragment.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
            Channel_Model channelModel = (Channel_Model) o;
            menu.setHeaderTitle(channelModel.getCh_Name());
            String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
            for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
            // Something with it...
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    class ListChannelsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    {
        private ChannelCountriesModel[] tabTitles;
        private String session;

        public ListChannelsPagerAdapter(String session, ChannelCountriesModel[] tabTitles)
        {
            this.tabTitles = tabTitles;
            this.session = session;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            try {
                return tabTitles.length;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return o == view;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabTitles[position].getName();
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // Inflate a new layout from our resources
            View rootView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.channels_list_tabs_pager_item, container, false);

            container.addView(rootView);

            ListView lv1;

            lv1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.channelList);
            lv1.requestFocus(); // Here is plan to fill listview

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);

        }

    }

}
```

Fragments are started from activity with following:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ChannelsListTabsFragment fragment = ChannelsListTabsFragment.newInstance(session, channelCountries, time_offset);
            transaction.replace(R.id.channels_list_tabs_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
```

Thank you very much for advice.
D

Comment: How are you populating the ListViews with data? Are you using an adapter?

Comment: Hello, Yes.Channel_Row_Adapter channel_Row_Adapter =  new Channel_Row_Adapter(lv1.getContext(), chanels, session);
            lv1.setAdapter(channel_Row_Adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(lv1);

Comment: Okay I will post an example of how to implement it from the activity.  How would you call the update from the activity? from a button, e.g....?

Comment: My idea is when I got event from EventBus - here is my test function public void onEvent(GetChannelsEvent event)
    {
        channelsCountriesMap = event.getGetChannelsEvent();
    } This is in my activity

Comment: Just added an answer. I do not have the exact class names as you so you would need to update the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would notify the adapter from the Activity

You can call this statement anywhere you like as long as the fragment is created.

```
if (channelsListTabsFragment != null) {
    channelsListTabsFragment.updateAdapter();
}
```

Activity Class

```
public class MainActivityTesting extends AppCompatActivity {
    ChannelsListTabsFragment channelsListTabsFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_testing);
        Fragment fragment = new ChannelsListTabsFragment();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        channelsListTabsFragment = (ChannelsListTabsFragment) fragment;
    }

    public void onEvent(GetChannelsEvent event) {
        channelsCountriesMap = event.getGetChannelsEvent();
        // Update fragment adapter within the onEvent. 
        if (channelsListTabsFragment != null) {
            channelsListTabsFragment.updateAdapter();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class ChannelsListTabsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    // Here your adapter will be updated
    // It is being called from the Activity 
    public void updateAdapter() {
        if (channel_Row_Adapter != null) {
            channel_Row_Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. But sorry for my bad knowing (I am beginner) but I still dont understand. Your solution is in fragment, but my fragment, i think, is creating tabs via pageviewer. And in this pageviewer I have channel_Row_Adapter defined and listview also. Here is old code with AsyncTask for downloading data, but not on change. http://pastie.org/10314973

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  You are trying to update channel_Row_Adapter  from the activity? Or call the asyncTask from the activity?

Comment: Or are you trying to retrieve different information when you change tabs

Comment: My app is relative simple. I have about 10 countries, and one country is one tab. In every tab is list listview with channels, for particular country. I need to refresh theese listviews, when I get new data. New data I get from service (at this moment), where I have eventbus, and structure is following - its HashMap, where index is country code and value is arraylist. So I need refresh all listviews, when I got new data. My opinion is, that this a can manage only from activity.

Comment: And asynctask in my code is for now - because I dont know, how to run update listviews when I get data.

Comment: How about calling the AsyncTask to refresh the data would that work?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know, how this manage on new data. I only can create listview. But I dont see any function to call anything again. But As I wrote - I am beginner. I see problem in ViewPager because I see only functions for creating. But nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply add a method to your ChannelsListTabsFragment class that returns the ListView?
Like

```
public ListView getListView() { return mListView; }
```

And call it from your activity, given you keep a reference to your ChannelsListTabsFragment object?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I still think, that fragment is not right place, because I have listview in PagerAdapter class defined. Or I am wrong?